# Raspberry Pi - How to print hex value?

Tags: python, windows, hex, putty, raspberry-pi3

I m using Python in Raspberry Pi and my packet is in hexadecimal value like `"0x750x010x010x060x000x08"`. I want serial communication between UART and Raspberry Pi so I wrote a program using Python in Raspberry Pi and I'm checking data on terminal but when I selected ASCII option in terminal it showing below output:

```
75
01
01
06
00
08
```

And when I selected hex option in terminal it is not showing above output. Now I want above output when I will select hex option but not ASCII option. So how to get that? If I need to convert it into hex or byte or any other than tell me the code in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import serial

port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=115200,timeout=3.0)

while True:
    a="0x750x010x010x060x000x08"
    b=a.replace("0x"," ")
    #print b 
    alist = b.split(" ")
    for element in alist
        port.write("\r\n"+str(element))
```

this gives the desired formatted data you want

Comment: thank u abhishek ..but this will give output in raspberry pi terminal...i want output in uart terminal by selecting hex option in uart terminal

Comment: please explain whole scenario so i can help you

Comment: i have attached snapshot of terminal window output ...u can see in my edited question..u can see in that i have selected ascii option but when i m selecting hex option it will not give this output...i want this same output when i select hex option ,i dont want this output in ascii option

Comment: means in simple i want "0x750x010x010x060x000x08" this same string as output in hex option but after remove 0x so when i select hex option output wll be 75 01 01 06 00 08 and when i select ascii option it give its ascii value

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `for` loop and `if` statment are used wrong here, and they are not required. The `while` loop can be equivently rewriten as:

```
a = "0x750x010x010x060x000x08"
b = a.replace("0x", " ")
while True:
      port.write("\r\n"+b)
```

Your main misanderstanding is that you assume Python understands you want to iterate over hex numbers. But it doesn't. In you original loop it just iterates the `a` string letter by letter. And in fact at each iteration of `for` loop you just changes the orignal `a` string to " 75 01 01 06 00 08" and send it as a string.

If you need to send bytes, you should split your string into separate records with each byte's infromation and convert these records to bytes.
Here is the code for that

```
a = "0x750x010x010x060x000x08"
b1 = a.split("0x") 
# b1 is ["", "75", "01", "01", "06", "00", "08"], the values are still strings
b2 = [int(x, 16) for x in b1[1:]] 
# b2 is a list of integers, the values calculated from strings assuming they are hex (16-bit) numbers
# use b1[1:] to cut the first blank string
b = str(bytearray(b2))
#b joins values list into a bytes string (each interger transformed into one byte)
while True:
      port.write("\r\n" + b)
```

Update for question in comments:
If `a` format is like this "0x750101060008", you just split it by 2 letters:

```
b1 = [a[2*i:2*i+2] for i in range(len(a)/2)]
```

Comment: thank u ...but this will give error like 
b2 = [int(x, 16) for x in b1]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ' '...so how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. The problem was that the split gives the first item with blank string.

Comment: thank u so much..it exactly give output what i want when select the hex option in terminal window from uart

Comment: one more question...plz give me solution...question is when my string is like "0x750101060008" inplace of "0x750x010x010x060x000x08" then how to convert it like "750101060008" and send on terminal

Comment: i mean when i m wring as above code to send 0x750101060008 packet, it gives error like: ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)...so how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    import serial

port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=115200,timeout=3.0)

while True:
    a="0x750x010x010x060x000x08"
    b=a.replace("0x"," ")
    #print b 
    alist = b.split(" ")
    for element in alist
        port.write("\r\n"+str(element))
```

this one

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).